# ThreeJS: Use BufferGeometry with Line

Tags: three.js, webgl, buffer-geometry

For performance reasons, I would like to migrate to `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry`. It works great for `Mesh` and `ParticleSystem` objects, but when setting the geometry of a `Line` to a `BufferGeometry`, `initLineBuffer()` expects a `geometry.vertices` Vector3 array which a BufferGeometry does not have.

The call stack:
render --> initWebGLObjects --> addObject --> initLineBuffers

Is there a simple solution for this, or do I need to hack? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like right now BufferGeometry will only draw out to triangles, so you you cannot have it draw lines (unless you do something like make the two of the three triangle vertices the same, but that is pretty hacky). It supports meshes and particles, so maybe soon it will support lines. [Here is the line in the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L3355)

Answer (score 4):

BufferGeometry does support lines now. Look at webgl_buffergeometry_lines.html example.

Comment: Direct link to example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_lines.html